# Confirming Navigation with custom hash history does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I use custom hash history in my app, the confirm navigation mechanism does not work.  I have modified the react-router confirm-navigation example to use custom hash history and successfully reproduced the problem.

I set the router leave hook (router.setRouteLeaveHook) and in the hook I return a string to indicate I do not want to leave the route.
When I push the BACK browser button, the browser URL will change to wherever the BACK button history navigates to, and reactRouter will correctly display a confirmation dialog box. On this dialog box I push the "cancel" button to indicate I don't want to leave the route, and my component remains visible and the route does not change. The problem is that the browser URL does not change back to where it was originally before I pressed the BACK button.

Is anyone else seeing this?

This is what I changed in examples/confirm-navigation/app.js to reproduce the problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link, useRouterHistory, withRouter } from 'react-router'

let myCustomHashAppHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })
```

and then in the app render I pass my myCustomHashAppHistory:

```
render((
  <Router history={myCustomHashAppHistory}>
    ...
    ...
```